# Are questions about sharing settings On Topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

With reference to [this](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/1103/wanhao-duplicator-i3-abs-settings) question: should questions about sharing settings for printers and slicers etc. be considered as on topic for this site?

Or looked at it differently: how can one turn a question such as the one linked into something more than a debate of settings that someone have used successfully? And if that is what the answers will be like, is that considered okey?

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends. There are no "best" settings for printing any one material, as the optimal settings will depend on the model being printed. I think questions of the format

> I have X printer, using Y settings, printing Z model in material W and I have V problem - how do I improve my settings?

would be *vastly* better than

> What is the best profile for printing material X with printer Y?

I suggest we close question of the latter format as "Unclear what you're asking". What settings you should use depends on much more than just the printer and material. An answer to the question of the former format would also be useful to a much wider audience (since it deals with a well-defined problem and fix for that problem), while an answer to the latter format is only useful for people using that specific printer and material.

Comment: I think your reasoning is very good. In particular for the less reliable desktop printers, there are simply no correct settings, as the settings will work differently with a few changes in bed-leveling - for instance. In such cases, the latter probably will not be well answerable at all.